# How to filter Alt key event for WM_DRAWITEM message

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

When I press Alt key, I received WM_DRAWITEM message in my win32 application, and result in the static controls re-draw, which is not the result I need. I only need the controls to be drawn on initialization. Why I reveived the WM_DRAWITEM message? and how can I disable it for Alt key?

Comment: You need to be able to draw the item at any time. For example, the window might be minimized and then restored, and now you need to redraw the item

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if Alt key was pressed from the Window procedure by handling WM_SYSCOMMAND message:

```
    case WM_SYSCOMMAND:

    if (wParam == SC_KEYMENU && (lParam >> 16) <= 0) // Alt key was pressed
        return 0;
    break;
```

Comment: Pressing Alt will cause a redraw to show accelerators.

Comment: My window(called A window) was contained in another window(called B window), I can get WM_SYSCOMMAND message in B window, but I can't in A window, so I can't filter Alt key in A window with the method you posted. Do you know how can I get WM_SYSCOMMAND message in A window? Thanks.

Comment: The method you posted will supress Alt key in whole application, I doubt it will have some risks. Can I just filter the Alt key in WM_DRAWITEM message response function?

Comment: I just work on SDI so I have no idea about MDI apps. WM_DRAWITEM won't send you key up/down messages so you can use flags. Just set a flag when Alt key is down and use that flag to skip redrawing of your controls.

Comment: I can get DRAWITEMSTRUCT in WM_DRAWITEM,  and I found the itemState value in the structure is 4(ODS_DISABLED) when I press Alt key, but it's 260(no definition on MSDN) on initialization and move out/back screen. It seems that I can fix the issue by checking itemState value, but I'm not very confident with this method.

Comment: 260 = 256 | 4. But it sounds like an XY problem. Why can't you draw the item twice?